# Can a colon be used after a helping verb like "is"?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, colons

I'm writing an answer to a science question and I'm not sure if I need a semicolon in the sentence.

> The problem for the experiment is; How do homing pigeons find their way home?

Comment: Colon (:) or semicolon(;)?

Comment: You need a colon, not a semicolon.

Comment: that and following the semi-colon, do not capitalize *How*

Comment: All you need is a comma. Also, enclose the interrogative in double quotes. *The problem for the experiment is, "How do homing pigeons find their way home?"*

Comment: @PeterShor Think again. What follows *is* is a mere noun phrase.

Comment: @Kris: You only use a comma if you use the quotes. Otherwise, you would use a colon. The difference between them is mostly a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a semicolon. A colon is more appropriate:

> The problem for the experiment is: How do homing pigeons find their way home?

More information on how to use semicolons or colons can be found by searching on the relevant tags: [semicolon](/questions/tagged/semicolon) and [colon](/questions/tagged/colon).

Answer (score -1):

There are several possibilities.  The easiest correction is as follows:  'The problem for the experiment is: *how* do homing pigeons find their *ways* home?'

*How* can either have a capital *h* or not, depending on how you view it: if you see it as a new sentence, then it best be capitalized; if you do not, then leave it in the miniscule.

I altered the original *way* to be plural, in accordance with plural *pigeons* and *their*.

Another option is to do as I did at the beginning of this answer: i.e. to put *as follows* after the verb *to be*.  Alternatively, you can say 'the problem is thus: ...', 'this is the problem: ...' or some such formation.

Perhaps the most complicated option is to recast the two separated clauses into a more contiguous sentence.  This may yield 'the problem for the experiment is to discover how homing pigeons find their ways home'.

This last possibility is the most pleasing to my ears, but those will give you enough scope to decide for yourself.

Comment: I would not pluralise _way_. I think the reason is that for me _find one's way_ is an idiom.

Comment: *Find their way* implies that they are travelling together; *find their ways* implies that they are travelling separately.

Comment: _Find their way_ does not have that implication for me.